# Will Nichrome heating element react with steam?

Tags: heating-systems, steam

I have a setup where nichrome heating element will be in contact with steam. Can it react with hot steam at 900 C? if it does, I can encase it in something like iron/stainless steel etc. If it doesn't i can use it directly.

From wikipedia: Nichrome wire, when heated to red-hot temperatures, develops an outer layer of chromium oxide. So reactions need to be assessed with chromium oxide.

I am using this as a supplemental heating because electricity is intermittent in my area. Also expensive. Will switch to solar thermal soon.

Appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Oxidation in steam is about the same as air so steam itself will not make a difference in life. However, are there any minerals in the steam ? A salt like sodium sulfate may cause "hot corrosion".

Comment: The steam is at 900 C. Does it make any difference?

Comment: That is getting near the top of the temperature range for long life with nichrome.